# Why RuntimeException not stop execution with finally block?

Tags: exception, runtimeexception

I ask an help to understand why this difference of behavior.

```
public class Test3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = new Test3().findPrice$withoutFinally();
  //Double d = new Test3().findPrice$withFinally();
    System.out.println(d);
}

private double findPrice$withoutFinally() {
    double price = -1.0;
    int attempt = 0;
    do {
        try {
            price = getPrice();
        } 
        catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught MyException!");
        } 
        attempt++;
    } while (attempt < 3);
    return price;
}

private double findPrice$withFinally() {
    double price = -1.0;
    int attempt = 0;
    do {
        boolean retry = false;
        try {
            price = getPrice();
        } 
        catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught MyException!");
        } 
        finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            if (retry) {
                System.out.println("retrying...");
                attempt++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }        
    } while (attempt < 3);
    return price;
}

private Double getPrice() throws MyException {
    if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Testing RE");
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I mean this, running findPrice$withoutFinally() method I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing RE

that is the behaviour thah I expect. But running findPrice$withFinally() method I got this unexpected (for me!) behaviour:

> finally
> -1.0

findPrice$withFinally() should not behave as findPrice$withoutFinally() and then stop execution because of the exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`finally` block is executed ALWAYS - when there is an exception and when there is no exception

Comment: Thanks for reply! This means that any RuntimeExeption generated inside getPrice() will be *IGNORED* by caller findPrice$withFinally()! Is there a way to avoid this, so when there is a RuntimeException (i.e NullPointerException) not caught by parent, execution code will break? Thanks